# How does aiohttp share a single connection for multiple requests?

Tags: python-3.x, request, connection, aiohttp

From the aiohttp [docs](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_advanced.html#client-session) I read:

```
The session contains a cookie storage and connection pool, thus cookies and connections are shared between HTTP requests sent by the same session.
```

I do not understand how aiohttp could send out the first parts of, say, 10 requests and then *over the same TCP connection* receive in random order fragments of *different* requests, which have to be pieced together ...

I cannot find anything about this sharing in the aiohttp docs, so I was hoping I could find some answers here ... ?

Comment: Oh man... just when I found a question that perfectly worded my exact question, it has 0 answers.

Comment: Ah, reading this back ... of course a TCP connection consists between 2 end-points and the server is oblivious of the nature of the client (aiohttp or whatever). So the best aiohttp can do is avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection by keeping them open for some time. Many applications communicate with the same server, so this may actually have a significant advantage. I'll delete this question soon.

Comment: right, but as I understand it now, aiohttp will only reuse a connection if an old one is freed up. so for concurrent connections it's use a new connection per request. is that not so?

Comment: Again, I'm only guessing here. But as a connection can only be used for a new request when it is 'freed up', as you say. That does not mean the connection has to be _re-established_. The already-open connection will be re-used. At least, that is where I'd think the gain would be.